# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php, how to use patch request in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a table name as berita, i want to update this table.

I try using patch in laravel 5.2.

**Routing**

```
route::resource("updateNews","test");
```

**Controller name as `berita`**

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = message::find($id);
    $user -> delete();
    return back();
```

}

**writenews.blade.php**
this how i call patch request. i just take a piece of my `<form>`

```
  <form action="updateNews" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
            {{ csrf_field()}}
      </from>
```

Comment: Hi Mate, if you use method Patch , the request will be sended to testController to `function edit` .... But in your for you are using method="post", and below PATCH , this is confusing...

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be :
**your Route:**

```
route::resource("updatenews","testController");
```

**Your TestController**

```
public function update ( Request $request,$id)
{
    $user = message::find($id);
    $user -> delete();
    return back();
}
```

**Your Form**

```
{!! Form::model($news, ['method' => 'PATCH','url' => ['updatenews', $news->id],'class' => 'form-horizontal' ]) !!}

 {{ csrf_field()}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Check our more about Laravel form: [Laravel Form Package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)